I need a Pythonista UI text display that I can append text to and it scrolls to the appended text
I am returning to Pythonista programming. I find that I often need to display subsequent lines of text results in a text control. I find that if I just use a UI textview that, due to strings being immutable, if I use something like:
 V[“textview”].text += “New line of text\n”

The textview always displays the text from the top. I then have to scroll manually to see the last appended line.
How can I do this?
I am struggling to work my way through the methods of View and Scroller to sort this out. Help would be appreciated. Steve, England

Have you tried TV.replace_range((len(TV.text), len(TV.text)), "New line of text\n")?

No I havn’t tried that but I have this on GitHub that is similar seems to work:
def add_text(txt):
tv = v["textview"]
tv.text += txt
tv.begin_editing()
l = len(tv.text)
tv.selected_range = (l, l)


Jason, I did try your suggestion but it did not work. Thanks, though, for your comment. The add_text function above does seem to do what I want.

I have found that a benign ValueError can occur so I’ve changed it:
def add_text(txt):
    """ Add text to the textview and scroll to the end."""
    
    tv = v["textview"]
    tv.text += txt
    tv.begin_editing()
    l = len(tv.text)
    try:
        tv.selected_range = (l, l)
    except ValueError:
        pass

